# how to change extended file attributes of files on mac?

Tags: macos, ls

I had some iOS projects in my macbook,one day I copied them to my pc which is based on windows system, then some day I copied them back to my macbook and I found the projects can not run.
I Opened one of the projects with Xcode, it says "builde successfully",but the app can not be deployed on the iPhone Simulator even if the Simulator is running!?!?!?! Then I check the files using "ls -l" command and found that the difference between normal Xcode project files and the new created Xcode project files is just a symbol.

files with problem:

```
    drwx------+ 49 dingvimer  staff   1.6K
```

normal file：

```
    drwx------@ 60 dingvimer  staff   2.0K
```

How can I change that '+' symbol to '@' and get the project run normally?

I will appreciate your kindness of helping me to figure it out (^-^).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ls -l@` to see extended attributes. It will show you something like:

```
drwxr-xr-x@ 5 cody  staff  170 Mar 30 08:46 test.xcodeproj
LastUpgradeCheck      4
```

LastUpgradeCheck - is the name of attribute (sometimes there can be something like com.apple.blablabla) and 4 - is the value.
 Use `xattr` command to set/delete extended attributes. See `man xattr` (its quite short and there are some examples).
Note, that you'll probably need to fix whole project directory.